Make subdivisions for a plane3d in the Bevy game engine v0.13
In the latest version v0.13 of the Bevy game engine, how do you go about making a mesh from a Plane3d shape with specified number of subdivisions?
In v0.12 you could do like this:
let mut mesh = Mesh::from(shape::Plane {
    size: 160.,
    subdivisions: 15,
});

I can't seem to find any convenience function to specify number of subdivisions for the new Plane3d shape that replaces the now deprecated shape::Plane 

According to chrisbiscardi on the bevy discord server:
According to https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/pull/11773 and a comment on the finite/infinite plane split PR (https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/pull/12426/files#r1555080768) subdivision on the new planes isn't implemented yet, so I'd continue using Plane instead of Plane3d if you need it, even though its deprecated.
also, according to the tracking issue it is planned and not yet done: https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/issues/10572
